# Docker intermittently failing when building image

Tags: linux, docker, containers, device-mapper

Does anybody know what might cause this?

This is running from Jenkins in AWS. The host is linux. The base is: FROM dockerfile/ubuntu

```
Step 4 : RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx
 ---> Running in f921a053a51d
time="2015-02-23T05:56:16Z" level="info" msg="Error getting container f921a053a51db43f12051e8608b6724f30bf3eb82df0efd33095ff0afa6ec403 from driver devicemapper: open /dev/mapper/docker-202:16-262147-f921a053a51db43f12051e8608b6724f30bf3eb82df0efd33095ff0afa6ec403: no such file or directory"
```

Comment: I faced similar problem on my machine, switched from the default 'devicemapper' driver to 'aufs' and so far, no more problems..
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) aufs-tools
sudo service docker restart

Comment: Is that run in the container or the host? Are there any issues I should be aware of? I.E. Will existing volume reload ok? etc...

Comment: run from host. After this I didn't get any more problems

Comment: @rups  I'd like to accept your answer but it is in a comment.